# Change Page Title on Add Node Page

Tags: hooks, 7

Which hook/filter do I need to use to modify the 'add node' page title (This Title)?  For example, when viewing "/node/add/" I want to change the title from 'Create ' to 'Add New '

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There are a few different ways you could do this, but the way you asked for would utilize [hook_form_alter()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--system--system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7):

```
<?php
function custom_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  if ($form_id == 'mynodetype_node_form') {
    drupal_set_title('My new title');
  }
}
?>
```

This would be in a custom module named custom.module... drupal_set_title(), when called anywhere in the page load, will set the title appropriately. You're basically hooking into the node form rendering process, and saying 'set the title to what I want' at that point.

If you'd like to further differentiate what the title would be depending on whether the user's creating a new node or editing an existing node, use [Devel](http://drupal.org/project/devel) module's dpm() function to print out the $form_state array, and check to see if there's a node ID already or not—if there is, you are editing a node; if not, you're creating a new node. Set the title appropriately.

While hook_form_alter() would probably be the most robust page (in case someone was viewing the node add form from somewhere other than node/add/[type]), you could also check the path in hook_init() and set the title there, or from a variety of other places (in Drupal 7, hook_page_alter() perhaps).

Comment: How can I tell if a form is new, or being edited?  For example, if I wanted a new node to say "Add a New node" and if the node is being edited, "Edit This Node"  Thank you for the answer above though, it is immensely helpful!

Comment: Check if the node has an nid already in the $form array. I forget which value has the nid in it, but it's in there, or the $form_state... if there *is* an nid, the user's editing the node. If there *isn't*, the node is a node add form...

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem and I had to write a module for that.

You can find my contributed my module [Node Add Title](http://drupal.org/project/node_add_title) for Drupal 7

> Node Add Title will let you change the title of the node creation pages and the node editing pages.

Hope it can help.